# Consequences of humanity beginning its roots on another continent?

Tags: alternate-worlds

I think it is commonly known that Africa was the "birth-continent" of modern humans. 
What (if any) sort of difference might we see of humanity uprooted from say ... South America? Or Australia?

Comment: What kind of difference you want to know? This is a very broad topic. Do you want skin color? Hairs? Socio-economic? What do you want to ask?

Comment: @Vylix is right.  A cool question but you could write a book about it. Narrow it down and bring it back.

Comment: If humans have evolved from New World monkeys, there probably would be a lot of differences. Or you want to do some handwaving and make great apes's home in the New World?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the continent. The first major civilizations appeared in the Fertile Crescent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fertile_Crescent), which is not exactly our place of birth, but really close.

There are plenty of conditions for a civilization to thrive: https://www.scribd.com/document/270998181/Conditions-of-Civilization.

But let's narrow them down, for simplicity. We want:
 - A major body of water, to simplify communications and make large scale agriculture possible.
 - A temperate climate, since tropical climates lead to disease being rampant and cold climates cannot sustain large populations in a very primitive technology state.
 - A relatively easy to traverse terrain: a collection of fertile valleys separated by rough terrain and high mountains would have lots of issues with communications and trade.

So, if we make the humans appear in North America first, we would expect to see a civilization emerge either in the Mississippi delta or in Mexico.

If they appear in South America, the Parana river would offer many of the conditions.

If they appear in East Asia, the Yellow river offers the most likely place for the first civilizations to appear.

If they appear in Central Asia, maybe they go for the Fertile Crescent anyway, or maybe they go for the Indus valley.

If they appear in Europe, then the first civilizations would probably use the Mediterranean for communication, with every river providing fresh water for agriculture in a minor coastal city.

So, depending on where you make humanity appear, you maximize the likelihood of the first major civilization appearing somewhere else than Egypt/Sumer.